# appium java - Unable to move seek bar in iOS App

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I tried below code to move the iOS seek bar. Please help me out to resolve it or am I doing anything wrong here? 
Note: I am not getting an error when I run this code but it's not moving seekbar at all.

```
WebElement seekBar = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(<elementXpath>));
int startX = seekBar.getLocation().getX();
int endX = seekBar.getSize().getWidth();
int yAxis = seekBar.getLocation().getY();
int end50X = (int) (startX + ((seekBar.getSize().getWidth()) * 0.51));
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(getDriver());
action.press(startX, yAxis).moveTo(end50X, yAxis).release().perform();
```

Comment: Did you get solution?